# Hibernate HQL to basic SQL (no joins)

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I working on a project with Hibernate and we need to replace Hibernate with some "home made persistence" stuff.
The idea is that the project is big enough, and we have many HQL queries.
The problem is with the queries like

```
select a,b from table1, table2 on t1.table1=t2.table2
```

Basically all joins are not supported by our "hand made persistence" stuff.

What I would need, is to be able to do some sort of transcoder, which will take as a input the HQL queries and output some SQL, but SQL without joins

I hope you get the idea.
My persistence layer does not supports joins.

Does anybody has any idea about something like that?
Some framework, or something?

Comment: No offense but throwing out an established ORM for a home-grown one is seriously reinventing the wheel.  You'd be better served by learning more about optimizing your HQL queries so they produce the best possible SQL.

Comment: I did not asked how to improve the HQL. This not the idea. I cannot explain more about why we change hibernate. We have some advantages changing hibernate.

Comment: "established" doesn't mean fully featured or non-buggy. Hibernate has some serious limitations in some areas, that haven't be addressed in 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what that example HQL is doing without a JOIN of some sort.
What you **can** do is implement the joins in a View and then use your home grown stuff to query the view. That insulates you from the implementation of the joins. The only way to get what you want without a JOIN somewhere is query each table and then merge the results in your code.

Comment: yes, this is an idea, but I have more that a 100 queries, so it's not possible to create views for every join I have.
I would need some generic translator.
I'm thinking at something like how hibernate translate the HQL, but when it does the joins, to change somehow.
It's complicated what I need, but I really need it.

Comment: JOINS do just what they say, they join the data of two or more tables together, there is no other way around it other than query each table and merge them together into your code, that is a really bad approach. Home grown means just that home grown, hand made code, only from the freshest bits. Get to coding.

Comment: When I sad home made, I meant we bought this, for some advantages that hibernate does not have, and if far more important that the joins.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you don't want to get rid of the joins but to express them in the very old SQL89 form. Either way it is still a join.

SQL92 Syntax:

```
SELECT FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

SQL89 Syntax:

```
SELECT FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2
WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

I am surprised anything that would cost money these days would fail to support an almost two decades old syntax.